# Запятая перед И: "Маша никогда не сердится(,) и этим она мне нравится"

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, ссп

Подскажите, пожалуйста, запятая перед И в данном случае нужна или нет? "Маша никогда не сердится и этим она мне нравится"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запятая нужна, так как это сложносочиненное предложение, состоящее из двух простых предложений.В предложении "Маша никогда не сердится, и этим она хороша"запятая нужна по той же причине. Если Вас устраивает мой ответ, кликните соответственно

Comment: Спасибо! А если бы было "Маша никогда не сердится и этим она хороша". Запятая была бы нужна?

Comment: Нужна. Две основы сохраняются: "Маша не сердится" и "она хороша".